# inserting ruby code breaks html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code with a `check` method that returns true or false

```
<%= link_to path, format: 'js' do %>
            <i class="<%= check ? "close\"></i>Unfollow member" : "open\"></i>Follow member></i>" %>
<% end %>
</div>
  <div class="list-group list-normal m-b-none">
```

but this outputs

```
<i class="close&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;Unfollow member
&lt;/a&gt;  &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class=" list-group="" list-normal="" m-b-none"="">
</i>
```

How can it be ? (I don't want to repeat the `check` statement inside and outside the `i` tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following will be more readable:

```
<% if check %>
  <i class="close">Unfollow member</i>
<% else %>
  <i class="open">Follow member></i>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**

To make it one liner:

```
<%= check ? "<i class='close'>Unfollow member</i>" : "<i class='open'>Follow member></i>" %>
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I want some one line statement ;) Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to path, format: 'js' do %>
  <i class="<%= check ? "'close'></i>Unfollow member" : "'open'></i>Follow member>" %></i>
<% end %>
```

I did not try. But if may works.